# JTextFields on top of active drawing on JPanel, threading problems

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, rendering, buffering

Has anyone ever tried to use Swing to construct a proper multi-buffered rendering environment *on top of which Swing user interface elements can be added*?

In this case I have an animating red rectangle drawn onto a background. The background does not need to be updated every frame so I render it onto a BufferedImage and redraw only the portion necessary to clear the previous location of the rectangle. See the complete code below, this extends the example given by @trashgod in a previous thread, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3119826/java-page-flipping-not-supported-on-mac-os).

So far so good; smooth animation, low cpu usage, no flickering.

Then I add a JTextField to the Jpanel (by clicking on any position on the screen), and focus on it by clicking inside the text box. Clearing the previous location of the rectangle now fails on every cursor blink, see the image below.

I am curious if anyone has an idea of why this might happen (Swing not being thread-safe? The image being painted asynchronously?) and in what direction to look for possible solutions.

This is on Mac OS 10.5, Java 1.6

[image: JPanel redraw fail]
<sub>(source: [arttech.nl](http://www.arttech.nl/javaredrawerror.png))</sub>

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.GraphicsConfiguration;
import java.awt.GraphicsDevice;
import java.awt.GraphicsEnvironment;
import java.awt.Insets;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.Transparency;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ComponentEvent;
import java.awt.event.ComponentListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.Timer;

public class NewTest extends JPanel implements 
    MouseListener, 
    ActionListener, 
    ComponentListener, 
    Runnable 
{

JFrame f;
Insets insets;
private Timer t = new Timer(20, this);
BufferedImage buffer1;
boolean repaintBuffer1 = true;
int initWidth = 640;
int initHeight = 480;
Rectangle rect;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new NewTest());
}

@Override
public void run() {
    f = new JFrame("NewTest");
    f.addComponentListener(this);
    f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    f.add(this);
    f.pack();
    f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    f.setVisible(true);
    createBuffers();
    insets = f.getInsets();
    t.start();
}

public NewTest() {
    super(true);
    this.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(initWidth, initHeight));
    this.setLayout(null);
    this.addMouseListener(this);
}

void createBuffers() {
    int width = this.getWidth();
    int height = this.getHeight();

    GraphicsEnvironment ge = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment();
    GraphicsDevice gs = ge.getDefaultScreenDevice();
    GraphicsConfiguration gc = gs.getDefaultConfiguration();

    buffer1 = gc.createCompatibleImage(width, height, Transparency.OPAQUE);        

    repaintBuffer1 = true;
}

@Override
protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    int width = this.getWidth();
    int height = this.getHeight();

    if (repaintBuffer1) {
        Graphics g1 = buffer1.getGraphics();
        g1.clearRect(0, 0, width, height);
        g1.setColor(Color.green);
        g1.drawRect(0, 0, width - 1, height - 1);
        g.drawImage(buffer1, 0, 0, null);
        repaintBuffer1 = false;
    }

    double time = 2* Math.PI * (System.currentTimeMillis() % 5000) / 5000.;
    g.setColor(Color.RED);
    if (rect != null) {
        g.drawImage(buffer1, rect.x, rect.y, rect.x + rect.width, rect.y + rect.height, rect.x, rect.y, rect.x + rect.width, rect.y + rect.height, this);
    }
    rect = new Rectangle((int)(Math.sin(time) * width/3 + width/2 - 20), (int)(Math.cos(time) * height/3 + height/2) - 20, 40, 40);
    g.fillRect(rect.x, rect.y, rect.width, rect.height);
}

@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    this.repaint();
}

@Override
public void componentHidden(ComponentEvent arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void componentMoved(ComponentEvent arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void componentResized(ComponentEvent e) {
    int width = e.getComponent().getWidth() - (insets.left + insets.right);
    int height = e.getComponent().getHeight() - (insets.top + insets.bottom);
    this.setSize(width, height);
    createBuffers();
}

@Override
public void componentShown(ComponentEvent arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
    JTextField field = new JTextField("test");
    field.setBounds(new Rectangle(e.getX(), e.getY(), 100, 20));
    this.add(field);
    repaintBuffer1 = true;
}

@Override
public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void mouseExited(MouseEvent arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void mousePressed(MouseEvent arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
}
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

`NewTest` extends `JPanel`; but because you're not painting every pixel on each call to `paintComponent()`, you need to invoke the super-class's method and erase the old drawing:

```
@Override
protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);
    int width = this.getWidth();
    int height = this.getHeight();
    g.setColor(Color.black);
    g.fillRect(0, 0, width, height);
    ...
}
```

Addendum: As you note, setting the background color in the constructor precludes the need to fill the panel in `paintComponent()`, while `super.paintComponent()` allows the text field(s) to function correctly. As you observe, the proposed workaround is fragile. Instead, simplify the code and optimize as warranted. For example, you may not need the complication of insets, extra buffers and a component listener.

Addendum 2: Note that `super.paintComponent()` calls the UI delegate's [`update()`](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17409_01/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/plaf/ComponentUI.html#update%28java.awt.Graphics,%20javax.swing.JComponent%29) method, "which fills the specified component with its background color (if its opaque property is true)." You can use `setOpaque(false)` to preclude this.

[image: Animation Test]

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.GraphicsConfiguration;
import java.awt.GraphicsEnvironment;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.Transparency;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ComponentAdapter;
import java.awt.event.ComponentEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.util.Random;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.Timer;

/** @see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3256941 */
public class AnimationTest extends JPanel implements ActionListener {

    private static final int WIDE = 640;
    private static final int HIGH = 480;
    private static final int RADIUS = 25;
    private static final int FRAMES = 24;
    private final Timer timer = new Timer(20, this);
    private final Rectangle rect = new Rectangle();
    private BufferedImage background;
    private int index;
    private long totalTime;
    private long averageTime;
    private int frameCount;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                new AnimationTest().create();
            }
        });
    }

    private void create() {
        JFrame f = new JFrame("AnimationTest");
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        f.add(this);
        f.pack();
        f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        f.setVisible(true);
        timer.start();
    }

    public AnimationTest() {
        super(true);
        this.setOpaque(false);
        this.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(WIDE, HIGH));
        this.addMouseListener(new MouseHandler());
        this.addComponentListener(new ComponentHandler());
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        long start = System.nanoTime();
        super.paintComponent(g);
        int w = this.getWidth();
        int h = this.getHeight();
        g.drawImage(background, 0, 0, this);
        double theta = 2 * Math.PI * index++ / 64;
        g.setColor(Color.blue);
        rect.setRect(
            (int) (Math.sin(theta) * w / 3 + w / 2 - RADIUS),
            (int) (Math.cos(theta) * h / 3 + h / 2 - RADIUS),
            2 * RADIUS, 2 * RADIUS);
        g.fillOval(rect.x, rect.y, rect.width, rect.height);
        g.setColor(Color.white);
        if (frameCount == FRAMES) {
            averageTime = totalTime / FRAMES;
            totalTime = 0; frameCount = 0;
        } else {
            totalTime += System.nanoTime() - start;
            frameCount++;
        }
        String s = String.format("%1$5.3f", averageTime / 1000000d);
        g.drawString(s, 5, 16);
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        this.repaint();
    }

    private class MouseHandler extends MouseAdapter {

        @Override
        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
            super.mousePressed(e);
            JTextField field = new JTextField("test");
            Dimension d = field.getPreferredSize();
            field.setBounds(e.getX(), e.getY(), d.width, d.height);
            add(field);
        }
    }

    private class ComponentHandler extends ComponentAdapter {

        private final GraphicsEnvironment ge =
            GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment();
        private final GraphicsConfiguration gc =
            ge.getDefaultScreenDevice().getDefaultConfiguration();
        private final Random r = new Random();

        @Override
        public void componentResized(ComponentEvent e) {
            super.componentResized(e);
            int w = getWidth();
            int h = getHeight();
            background = gc.createCompatibleImage(w, h, Transparency.OPAQUE);
            Graphics2D g = background.createGraphics();
            g.clearRect(0, 0, w, h);
            g.setColor(Color.green.darker());
            for (int i = 0; i < 128; i++) {
                g.drawLine(w / 2, h / 2, r.nextInt(w), r.nextInt(h));
            }
            g.dispose();
            System.out.println("Resized to " + w + " x " + h);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. 

If you add super.paintComponent(g) and run the test application I provided, you will see that unfortunately this is not a solution. The default paintComponent method of JPanel clears its background, which makes it necessary to redraw the entire background image, mostly defeating the purpose of pre-rendering the background image.

I have a hunch that redrawing only the area necessary should be possible, but as it seems, there is some issue with redrawing the textfield in a different thread than redrawing the background image that causes these drawing artifacts..

Comment: Regarding the addendum: many thanks again for taking the time to dive into this. I realize that your point, being that there is no way that the automatically redrawing JTextFields will work correctly together with active redrawing *without* using super.paintComponent(g), is correct. Nonetheless using super.paintComponent(g) implies that the entire window has to be redrawn on every animation frame, making the cpu usage dependent on the window size, which is what I would like to prevent. So my question is answered, but my problem is still standing. I'll make a new post about this.

Comment: @Mattijs: Using setOpaque(false) will avoid the fill. I've updated the example to show the paint time. The difference is considerable, but it must be weighed against the effort to manage updates.

Comment: @Mattijs: BTW, I didn't mean to pre-empt your asking a new question; the paint time display may help narrow the scope.

Comment: @trashgod: thanks for the useful additions.

Here is my follow-up, where I elaborate on this test code and summarize my findings: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3289336/swing-active-rendering-efficiency-or-how-to-combine-active-rendering-with-gui-wid

Comment: @Mattjis: Updated example to build GUI on EDT; sorry for the error.

Comment: Noob question here, what does the timer actually do in this code? You start a timer and don't use it anywhere.

Comment: The timer periodically invokes `actionPerformed()` on the EDT; see [*How to Use Swing Timers*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html).

Answer (score 2):

I found a workaround.

What I think was happening: whenever a JTextfield needs to be updated (i.e. on every cursor blink), JPanel's overridden paintComponent() is called, but with a different Graphics argument than when called by repaint(). Thus on every cursor blink, my rectangle was cleared and redrawn on a wrong Graphics instance, leaving the Graphics seen on screen invalid.

Does this make any sense? If it does, isn't this a weird inconvenience in Swing?

Anyway, by keeping a boolean (`activeRedraw`) of where the invoke comes from, it looks like I managed to work around this issue. So it seems I finally found a way to do active drawing without repainting the entire screen area on every frame, which means low cpu usage independent of the window size!

Complete code here:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.GraphicsConfiguration;
import java.awt.GraphicsDevice;
import java.awt.GraphicsEnvironment;
import java.awt.Insets;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.Transparency;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ComponentEvent;
import java.awt.event.ComponentListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.Timer;

public class NewTest extends JPanel implements 
    MouseListener, 
    ActionListener, 
    ComponentListener, 
    Runnable 
{

    JFrame f;
    Insets insets;
    private Timer t = new Timer(20, this);
    BufferedImage buffer1;
    boolean repaintBuffer1 = true;
    int initWidth = 640;
    int initHeight = 480;
    Rectangle rect;
    boolean activeRedraw = true;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new NewTest());
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        f = new JFrame("NewTest");
        f.addComponentListener(this);
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        f.add(this);
        f.pack();
        f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        f.setVisible(true);
        createBuffers();
        insets = f.getInsets();
        t.start();
    }

    public NewTest() {
        super(true);
        this.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(initWidth, initHeight));
        this.setLayout(null);
        this.addMouseListener(this);
    }

    void createBuffers() {
        int width = this.getWidth();
        int height = this.getHeight();

        GraphicsEnvironment ge = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment();
        GraphicsDevice gs = ge.getDefaultScreenDevice();
        GraphicsConfiguration gc = gs.getDefaultConfiguration();

        buffer1 = gc.createCompatibleImage(width, height, Transparency.OPAQUE);        

        repaintBuffer1 = true;
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        //super.paintComponent(g);
        int width = this.getWidth();
        int height = this.getHeight();

        if (activeRedraw) { 
            if (repaintBuffer1) {
                Graphics g1 = buffer1.getGraphics();
                g1.clearRect(0, 0, width, height);
                g1.setColor(Color.green);
                g1.drawRect(0, 0, width - 1, height - 1);
                g.drawImage(buffer1, 0, 0, null);
                repaintBuffer1 = false;
            }

            double time = 2* Math.PI * (System.currentTimeMillis() % 5000) / 5000.;
            g.setColor(Color.RED);
            if (rect != null) {
                g.drawImage(buffer1, rect.x, rect.y, rect.x + rect.width, rect.y + rect.height, rect.x, rect.y, rect.x + rect.width, rect.y + rect.height, this);
            }
            rect = new Rectangle((int)(Math.sin(time) * width/3 + width/2 - 20), (int)(Math.cos(time) * height/3 + height/2) - 20, 40, 40);
            g.fillRect(rect.x, rect.y, rect.width, rect.height);

            activeRedraw = false;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        activeRedraw = true;
        this.repaint();
    }

    @Override
    public void componentHidden(ComponentEvent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void componentMoved(ComponentEvent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void componentResized(ComponentEvent e) {
        int width = e.getComponent().getWidth() - (insets.left + insets.right);
        int height = e.getComponent().getHeight() - (insets.top + insets.bottom);
        this.setSize(width, height);
        createBuffers();
    }

    @Override
    public void componentShown(ComponentEvent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
        JTextField field = new JTextField("test");
        field.setBounds(new Rectangle(e.getX(), e.getY(), 100, 20));
        this.add(field);
        repaintBuffer1 = true;
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
}
```

Comment: Note: on Windows, the behavior is once again different and the workaround is not sufficient.

Comment: I've elaborated in my answer.