# Correctly finding frame rate on a custom Java Component

Tags: java, swing, awt, frame-rate, jcomponent

I am not confident my framerate code is correct, and I have not been able to find exact examples of what I am looking for.

Essentially I have subclassed `java.awt.Component`, and inside the `paint(Graphics)` method I call my `calculateFrameRate()` function, which is shown below. I don't do any incremental drawing in `update()`. The numbers from this seem high, and I am wondering if the inherent double buffering of the Component class means that paint is being called twice as much as it is being rendered? I'm rusty on the double-buffer stuff though, that may be totally incorrect.

Here is the frame rate method:

```
 private List<Long> updateTimes = new ArrayList<Long>();

private void calculateFrameRate() {
    long time = System.currentTimeMillis();

    updateTimes.add(new Long(time));

    // We will have the wrong framerate for the first 30 draws. No big.
    float timeInSec = (time - updateTimes.get(0)) / 1000f;

    currentFrameRate_ = 30f / timeInSec;

    if (updateTimes.size() == 31)
        updateTimes.remove(0);

}
```

Cheers,

Hamy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As an alternative, you could look at `System.nanoTime()`. This [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3256941) calculates an average over the preceding number of frames defined by `FRAMES`.

Comment: Turns out that my method accurately matches the example you gave.  Well, mostly ;) Only for complex painting. My method measures not just the time in the paint function, but also counts time between paints as well. If you have simple painting, the given example will miss a relatively large percentage of the total time because the time required to paint is such a small percent of total, and thus give you a much higher fps. I don't know if there is a 'right' answer on fps calculation, but I'm going with frames per total seconds, not frames per seconds-spent-in-the-paint-method ;)

Comment: I see your point: I'm usually trying to minimize the time spent in `paint()`, but you're looking at optimizing the overall rate (fps).