# Java double buffer using an override for update method throws stack overflow

Tags: java, overriding, stack-overflow, doublebuffered

I am trying to achieve double buffering of my game in Java by overriding the update method for my JPanel, I do all the usual code etc and still it won't work, it throws a stack overflow error, below is the specific error:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.StackOverflowError
        at java.awt.Rectangle.<init>(Rectangle.java:193)
        at java.awt.Rectangle.<init>(Rectangle.java:208)
        at sun.awt.image.BufImgSurfaceData.getBounds(BufImgSurfaceData.java:369)
        at sun.java2d.loops.GraphicsPrimitive.convertFrom(GraphicsPrimitive.java:533)
        at sun.java2d.loops.GraphicsPrimitive.convertFrom(GraphicsPrimitive.java:523)
        at sun.java2d.loops.MaskBlit$General.MaskBlit(MaskBlit.java:171)
        at sun.java2d.loops.Blit$GeneralMaskBlit.Blit(Blit.java:186)
        at sun.java2d.pipe.DrawImage.blitSurfaceData(DrawImage.java:927)
        at sun.java2d.pipe.DrawImage.renderImageCopy(DrawImage.java:550)
        at sun.java2d.pipe.DrawImage.copyImage(DrawImage.java:54)
        at sun.java2d.pipe.DrawImage.copyImage(DrawImage.java:982)
        at sun.java2d.SunGraphics2D.drawImage(SunGraphics2D.java:2979)
        at sun.java2d.SunGraphics2D.drawImage(SunGraphics2D.java:2964)
        at epicgame.Menu.displayMenu(Menu.java:71)
        at epicgame.GUI$1.paintComponent(GUI.java:64)
        at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1029)
        at epicgame.GUI$1.update(GUI.java:117)
        at epicgame.GUI$1.paintComponent(GUI.java:98)
        at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1029)
```

My code isn't particularly complex either:

```
mainPanel = new JPanel()
        {
            @Override protected void paintComponent(Graphics g)
            {
                //super.paintComponent(g);

                if(menuEnabled == 1)
                {
                    Menu.displayMenu(g, mainPanel);
                }
                else if(gameNum == 1)
                { 
                    StreetFighter.StreetFighter(g, mainPanel);

                    // Calls the controls method within the controls class.
                    Controls.controls(Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis() - timeOld);
                    timeOld = Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis();
                }
                else if(gameNum == -1)
                {
                    Menu.scoreBoard(g, mainPanel);
                    if(loaded != true)
                    {
                        Menu.loadScoreBoard(mainPanel);
                        loaded = true;
                    }
                }
                if(gameNum > 0)
                {
                    if(longcat == true && longcatloaded != true)
                    {
                        Extras.loadLongCat();
                        longcatloaded = true;
                    }
                    if(longcatloaded == true && longcat == true)
                    {
                        Extras.displayLongCat(g, mainPanel);
                    }
                }

                // Causes an infinite loop, e.g makes the screen render over and over.
                //repaint();
                update(g);
            }

            @Override public void update(Graphics g)
            {
                System.err.println("Updating screen and using double buffer!");

                // initialize buffer
                if(dbImage == null)
                {
                    dbImage = createImage (this.getSize().width, this.getSize().height);
                    dbg = dbImage.getGraphics ();
                }
                // clear screen in background
                dbg.setColor (getBackground ());
                dbg.fillRect (0, 0, this.getSize().width, this.getSize().height);
                // draw elements in background
                dbg.setColor (getForeground());

                paint(dbg);

                // draw image on the screen
                g.drawImage (dbImage, 0, 0, this);

                try
                {
                    Thread.sleep(200);

                }
                catch (InterruptedException ex)
                {
                    System.err.print("cant delay repaint.");
                }
            }
        };
```

I was hoping someone could point out where I went wrong, I'm thinking maybe something to do with the update being called too many times, or possible update is the wrong method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't call `paint()` or `update()` methods from `paintComponent()`.

Also don't call `Thread.sleep()` in any painting methods.  Instead, create a thread that updates your game model every x milliseconds and then calls `repaint()` on your custom component where you have overridden `paintComponent()` so that it draws the game state.

Comment: what would I use to to the double buffering with then?

Comment: +1 Double buffering is a feature of `JPanel`; just use the relevant constructor. Here's an [example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3256941).

Answer (score 1):

You're calling `paint` within the component's `paintComponent`, which will cause the component to keep repainting itself. This will cause a `StackOverflowException`. Also, the [API](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#paint%28java.awt.Graphics%29) admonishes a developer about explicitly invoking `paint` in an application:

> Invoked by Swing to draw components.
>   Applications should not invoke paint
>   directly, but should instead use the
>   repaint method to schedule the
>   component for redrawing.
>
> This method actually delegates the
>   work of painting to three protected
>   methods: paintComponent, paintBorder,
>   and paintChildren. They're called in
>   the order listed to ensure that
>   children appear on top of component
>   itself. Generally speaking, the
>   component and its children should not
>   paint in the insets area allocated to
>   the border. Subclasses can just
>   override this method, as always. A
>   subclass that just wants to specialize
>   the UI (look and feel) delegate's
>   paint method should just override
>   paintComponent.

Comment: I need this, as the basis of my whole game relies on its continual refreshing. :/

Comment: @Luke: One way to go about it is to check the variables `gameNum` and `menuEnabled` whenever their values are altered (or periodically through use of a timer or executor service). If they meet a certain condition, set a `global` flag and subsequently call `repaint` (and possibly `removeAll` prior). And then, check that flag in `paintComponent` and perform the appropriate drawing.

Comment: Thanks, I will take that into consideration in the future.

Answer (score 0):

You need to call `g.dispose()` every frame after you are done with it, otherwise it will never be released from memory and you get the stack overflow error you see.  http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.3/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics.html

Comment: after adding this at the bottom of my update method i still recieve the stack overflow. Help.

Comment: This is required "only if it was created directly from a component or another `Graphics` object." Also, it might help to cite a more recent API.

Comment: API link was the first Google result, pretty sure it still applies.  Not sure about the specifics of when you need to dispose, but if you're doing double buffering in Java, you're doing active rendering (not passive rendering), which requires that you do a manual `dispose()` call after each frame rendered.

Comment: Either link makes it [clear](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics.html) that your suggestion is wrong in this context.