# Map lat long to x y for moon

Tags: java, swing, maps, geospatial, projection

**Edit: Now I'm pretty sure this map is an equirectangular projection, which has a pretty simple formula to figure out. If I'm not mistaken, the OP's first code snippet in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14329691/covert-latitude-longitude-point-to-a-pixels-x-y-on-mercator-projection) is what I need.**

First off, this is a project for a Java-based data structures class in college, but isn't due for another month and a half, so no worries (yet) about time.

My project is taking named crater location data and mapping it to a projection of the moon, so that selecting a crater from a table will highlight it on the image and give information about it in JLabels below the image.

I know that converting lat long to (x,y) depends entirely on the projection, but I am having issues 1) knowing what projection I am using, and 2) deriving the formula once I know the projection.

So, I want to take [this map](http://astrogeology.usgs.gov/search/details/Moon/Kaguya/TC/Ortho/v02/Lunar_Kaguya_TC_Ortho_Global_64ppd_v02/cub) and draw on it using Swing (a sample image is in the upper-left corner, opens in browser to look at). This is listed as a "simple cylindrical" planetographic projection, but I'm having trouble deciding what that means. I'm wondering if it's an Equirectangular projection, but what kind of cylindrical projection is this, really? Once we know that, how would I go about figuring up a formula to convert the lat-longs from my database to x-y on this map?

I'm less concerned about pinpoint accuracy than just making it work, if that matters. There's extra assignment points for a graphical representation of the data we're manipulating, so just being present is enough to get the points.

Thanks in advance for the help. If you need any more info to answer this, I'll be glad to provide it.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because at this stage, this isn't a programming problem. It's a "I don't know what I'm supposed to do" problem

Comment: [_Equirectangular projection_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equirectangular_projection) is suitable for the approach examined [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/32170318/230513).

Comment: Thanks for the help.