# Does JavaFX have a method like the C _setwindow function?

Tags: java, javafx

The `_setwindow()` function in C enabled the `width` and `height` in pixels to be replaced by user defined double dimensions.

For example: `_setwindow(YES, 0.00, 0.00, 5.50, 3.00);` `YES` changed the `0,0` from the top left to the bottom left, and made the X range from `0.00` to `5.50`, and the Y range from `0.00` to `3.00`. Graphics could be assigned using X,Y coordinates within the assigned ranges, instead of pixels.

My question: Is there a comparable method in JavaFX?

Comment: Can you explain what you are trying to do/achieve? This sounds a bit like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: I want to draw a global map that uses X,Y coordinates in a window, derived from global latitude and longitude readings.  Outlines of continents, national boundaries, etc

Comment: Please edit your question to reflect this use case. See also [*Implementing a mouse click event on a tile in a map*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32170318/230513).