# How do I set up a JFrame with a refresh rate?

Tags: java, jframe

I have a 2d game which the entire structure is completely coded except the graphics. I am just updating the single component of a JFrame which is a Graphic containing 50 images. Each frame the images are in a different location hence the need for a refresh rate.

To paint, I have overridden the paintComponent() method, so all I really need to do is repaint the component (which, again, is just a Graphic) every 40ms.

How do you set up a JFrame with 25FPS?

Comment: I guess you don't want to update a JFrame with 25 fps, but some content of it. Do you use Java3D? Do you use OpenGL? What is the parent class of your display panel (jpanel, widget, ...)?

Comment: Kind of a broad question and as stated, I think unanswerable.

Comment: @Hovercraft Full of Eels: that should be specific enough now. Tell me if any more details are needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This [`AnimationTest`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3256941) uses [`javax.swing.Timer`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/Timer.html). A period of 40 ms would give a rate of 25 Hz.

```
private final Timer timer = new Timer(40, this);
```

Addendum: The timer's `ActionListener` responds by invoking `repaint()`, which subsequently calls your overridden `paintComponent()` method

```
@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    this.repaint();
}
```

Comment: And this is just added on to the end of the public static void main method?

Comment: @Will: Yes, as long as you are on the [event dispatch thread](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html), typically after `setVisible()`.

Answer (score 6):

It's a bad idea to refresh a JFrame. It's one of the few heavy components in Swing. The best way is to

- identify the Panel that contains your animation
- create a class that extends JPanel . i.e. GamePane extends JPanel
- override paintComponent (no s)

Your title is misleading, you did the right thing.

- in your JFrame create a runner class

---

```
/** Thread running the animation. */
private class Runner extends Thread
{
    /** Wether or not thread should stop. */
    private boolean shouldStop = false;
    /** Pause or resume. */
    private boolean pause = false;

    /** Invoke to stop animation. */
    public void shouldStop() {
        this.shouldStop = true;
    }//met

    /** Invoke to pause. */
    public void pauseGame() { pause = true; }//met
    /** Invoke to resume. */
    public void resumeGame() { pause = false; }//met

    /** Main runner method : sleeps and invokes engine.play().
     * @see Engine#play */
    public void run()
    {
        while( !shouldStop )
        {
            try {
                Thread.sleep( 6 );
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }//catch
            if( !pause )
            {
                engine.play();
                                    gamePane.repaint();

            }//if
        }//while
    }//met

    /** Wether or not we are paused. */
    public boolean isPaused() {
        return pause;
    }//met
}//class Runner (inner)
```

Your animation will be much smoother. And use MVC and events to refresh other parts of UI.

Regards,
 Stéphane