# Reload/Refresh JFrame window on button click

Tags: java, swing, arraylist, jbutton, jlabel

I have tried a lot of thinks in last two days and I just can't refresh the Frame :/
I connect on my database and make a select query... In my console window I see 4 ID-s On my form too... After I make another data in my database, in my console window i see 5 ID-s but on my form 4... If I put `frame.setvisible` on my button another form appears...

Here is my class:

```
JLabel timeLabel;


private JPanel contentPane;
 private ArrayList<JLabel> lbllist= new ArrayList<JLabel>();
 private ArrayList<JButton> btnlist= new ArrayList<JButton>();
static int brojac = 0;
private JLabel lblNewLabel;
private JButton btnRefresh;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try {


                Mainframe = new Main();
                frame.setVisible(true);

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
}
           //constructor (I need every time to see data from the database)
               public Main() {


    getContentPane().setLayout(null);

    lblNewLabel = new JLabel("New label");
    lblNewLabel.setBounds(0, 185, 46, 14);
    getContentPane().add(lblNewLabel);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setBounds(100, 100, 800, 300);
    contentPane = new JPanel();
    contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
    setContentPane(contentPane);
    contentPane.setLayout(null);

    getContentPane().removeAll();
    btnRefresh = new JButton("Refresh");
    btnRefresh.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            do_btnRefresh_actionPerformed(arg0);
        }
    });
    btnRefresh.setBounds(335, 228, 89, 23);
    contentPane.add(btnRefresh);

    EntityManager em = Connection.getEmf().createEntityManager();
    TypedQuery<Entity> query = em.createQuery(
            "select n from Entityn where finished= 0",
            PokusajNarudzbe.class);
    List<Entity> resultList = query.getResultList();
    int a = 20;
    for (Entitypokusaj entity: resultList) {

        System.err.println(entity.getName());//here i see all data (but not
                                                   //in the form

        JLabel list= new JLabel(entity.getBrojName());
        lista.setBounds(10, a, 200, 20);
        lista.setText(entity.getNarudzbaID() + " "
                + entity.Name() + " ";
        lbllist.add(list);
        getContentPane().add(list);
        list.setVisible(true);
        list.repaint();
        list.revalidate();
        JButton btn= new JButton(entity.getName());
        btn.setBounds(500, a, 200, 20);
        btn.setText("Gotovo");
        btnlist.add(btn);
        getContentPane().add(btn);
        a += 20;
        gumb.setVisible(true);
        gumb.repaint();
        gumb.revalidate();
    }

    getContentPane().repaint();
    resultList.clear();
    em.clear();
    em.close();

}
`               protected void do_btnRefresh_actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
    Main frame1 = new Main();
    SwingUtilities.updateComponentTreeUI(frame1);
    frame1.invalidate();
    frame1.validate();
    frame1.repaint();
//      frame1.revalidate();
//      frame1.setVisible(true); (if I uncomment this another form apears...)

}


@Override
public int read(CharBuffer arg0) throws IOException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return 0;
}
}
```

What can I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't fetch your data from the DB inside a constructor.  This way you can't update the form - it only loads data when it's being created. Move the data fetching logic to a separate method and call it in your button click handler.

What you have right now will only create new forms, NOT update the original one. That's why if you uncomment the `setVisible` part another form opens.

Comment: Just one more question...
How can I reload this form every 30 sec without button?

Comment: Use a timer - see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6260744/how-do-i-set-up-a-jframe-with-a-refresh-rate).

Comment: I can't implement these timers... I made a function service() which calls the database and draw the labels and buttons... I think i need an action to be repeated every 30 seconds but I don't know how :(
I hope you can help me...
Thank you

Comment: See [here](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0240__Swing/SwingTimeraction.htm) - in your case the `timer` should be assigned more or less like this `timer = new Timer(30000, new ActionListener() { public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {service();}});`. It would be better to place your database access in a separate thread as @rimero suggested, but I guess as you're learning it may be better to take one step at a time.