# Java animation periodical action

Tags: java, swing, animation

I have animation and I need it to periodically do something. How can I achieve that? I guess it could be done with another thread and sleep him for specified time. However I'm not sure about this solution.

Animation is very simple.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

if you want to moving with something in the Swing then you have to use [javax.swing.Timer](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html), example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7206122/swing-rate-limiting/7207550#7207550)

Answer (score 4):

You will definitely want to use the [Java Timing Framework](http://java.net/projects/timingframework/pages/Home). It was created by the guys that wrote [Filthy Rich Clients](http://filthyrichclients.org/) which is about making very rich Swing apps. Writing your own timers/threads to do this is difficult to do right, plus the timing framework is clean and has helper methods ready to go.