# Questions about BufferedImages and Images

Tags: java, image, bufferedimage

Please answer these questions:

1. Is it true that if a BufferedImage is of type INT_ARGB it will be rendered at the same speed as a Toolkit generated Image object?
2. Are BufferedImages and Images "equal" for games? (speed & memory efficiency wise)
3. Is it correct that BufferedImages will not play an animated *.gif because the image data is buffered?
4. Will the animated image data stored in an Image object be lost if the Image is drawn to a BufferedImage which is then rendered to the screen through a Graphics object?

Comment: What do your tests and profiling tell you?

Comment: To be honest, I haven't done any one those things. I was kind of hoping that someone would have an answer.

Comment: Well I have tried drawing images that were animating just fine, until they were drawn on a BufferedImage. So I guess I kind of know the answer to question number 3 & 4. I just didn't want to draw a hasty conclusion, and so I thought someone could answer my questions or at least confirm my "theories" in a snap :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While `BufferedImage` is not intrinsically animated, they are frequently used to pre-load or pre-render complex images in order to speed up animation. This [`KineticModel`](https://sites.google.com/site/drjohnbmatthews/kineticmodel) is an example. This [`AnimationTest`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3256269/jtextfields-on-top-of-active-drawing-on-jpanel-threading-problems/3256941#3256941) shows one way to examine rendering time.

Comment: Thanks that explained a lot :)