# Java game: Keeping framerate the same on all computers

Tags: java, frame-rate

COMPLETE EDIT:

After reading comments, I changed to a Timer with Timer(33,this);, however on my laptop it's repeating at 47 (and constantly bouncing around to other numbers) whereas my computer stays at the perfect 33.

Is there a common problem with timers I'm missing here? Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

I dont think you are taking the right approach, you shouldn't try to keep all the computers running at the same FPS, in fact no game that I know does that. Instead you should make sure that every x fraction of time the same movements happen regardless of the fps for that particular computer.

Comment: +1; agreed--FPS isn't what's important, what's important is keeping game time in sync.

Answer (score 1):

Time Based Animation is what you want to be looking at.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`javax.swing.Timer`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/Timer.html), as shown in this [`AnimationTest`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3256269/jtextfields-on-top-of-active-drawing-on-jpanel-threading-problems/3256941#3256941).