# How to measure Java2D drawing performance in a JComponent?

Tags: java, swing, java-2d, measurement, frame-rate

I'm trying something along these lines:

```
private static class TexturePanel extends JPanel {

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics graphics) {

        // drawing code

        // calc fps

        repaint();
    }
}
```

Is calling `repaint()` in `paintComponent()` the right approach to this?

Comment: no, that's wrong. paintComponent is eventually called from repaint, so you'r creating a full circle

Comment: @Brogrammer: I'm measuring drawing performance, that's why I want an immediate repaint.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How to measure Java2D drawing performance in a JComponent?

A crude measure is to give the repaint [`Timer`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/Timer.html) an arbitrarily short delay & count FPS.

> Is calling `repaint()` in `paintComponent()` the right approach to this?

No.  No it isn't.  `paintComponent()` is fine, but don't trigger `repaint()` from within the method.  See the [Performing Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/) Lesson of the Java Tutorial for some tips.

If you cannot get it sorted from that, I suggest you prepare and post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) of your best effort.

Comment: See also [`AnimationTest`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3256269/jtextfields-on-top-of-active-drawing-on-jpanel-threading-problems/3256941#3256941).