# Calculating points on an elliptical orbit in 3D

Tags: java, geometry, trigonometry, ellipse

I'm required to move my virtual camera from Point A in 3D space to Point B in an elliptical orbit. So far, I have:

- Calculated the projected lines from the center of each camera position (i.e. extended the front vector infinitely).
- Used this to calculate the minimum distance between these 2 projected lines which will act as the center for my ellipse.
- Visualized the 3D skewed plane in which I need to perform the movement.

But now I am stuck! I'm (obviously) not a mathematician so I'm having a hard time getting my head around what I need to do next.

I have 2 points on this elliptical arc (although I have no idea where they are on the circumference, and so have no idea what the major and minor axis limits are; `a` and `b` in conventional notation I believe?) 
Currently, the movement between these 2 points is linear so I can use that as a starting base in case that is any sort of help? Could someone please guide me in the right direction?

Comment: If you don't need an actual elliptical movement, but just a "curvy" movement, it would be simpler to use splines.

Answer (score 1):

Although 2D, this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3256269/jtextfields-on-top-of-active-drawing-on-jpanel-threading-problems/3256941#3256941) that uses the [parametric form in canonical position](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ellipse#Parametric_form_in_canonical_position) may offer some insight.

Comment: Thanks for the response. That certainly does help but I still have the problem of not knowing `a` and `b` e.g. my two arbitrary points may not be the major and minor axes. They may just be 20 degrees apart for example and neither may lie on the major and/or minor axis. Is there any way to calculate the major and minor axis given a center point and 2 perimeter points?

Comment: [An ellipse in the plane has five degrees of freedom](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ellipse#Degrees_of_freedom); two is not enough. Since you know the center, maybe the [polar form relative to center](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ellipse#Polar_form_relative_to_center) would be useful. Aren't _a_ and _b_ arbitrary for "an elliptical orbit?"

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. That confirms the conclusion I came to. Without making a lot of assumptions, it isn't possible to do. I was under the impression that `a` and `b` were the magnitude of the semi-major and semi-minor axes? Or am I way out of whack? If so, the polar form would be exactly what I need!

Comment: Yes; I've also seen _a_ called the major radius and _b_ called the minor radius.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand you want to calculate the point of the ellipse. You can use the ellipse equation: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ellipse
or if you do not have the center, height, width of the ellipse, then you can assign spline on the give points: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spline_%28mathematics%29