# Java Swing 2D animation

Tags: java, swing, animation, 2d

i'm using eclipse platform and window builder pro within. I've already created new project (window builder -> swing designer -> application window); Now I want my app to show some 2D animation (for example rectangle that moves) without blinking screen. What's the best way to do that? Right now i have only these methods in my code: MainWindow() constructor, initialize() and main(String[] args)

I've already read some info about displaying a 2D Graphics, but they all use different components and idk which way is the best and i don't always understand the methods that they use.

Comment: Pretty tired of seeing useful questions "closed as not constructive".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A simple animation demo I wrote a while ago to get you started (has some other dependencies within the project)

http://tus.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/tus/tjacobs/animation/

Comment: See also [TUS](https://sourceforge.net/projects/tus/), as well as this related [example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3256941/230513).

Comment: ok, i've got it already, thanks)

Comment: @trashgod another one, very bad for Java & Swing community that this man didn't survived *Sun_To_Oracle_Xxx*

Answer (score 4):

I recently made an **open-source** [application](https://plus.google.com/110022050602256925286/posts/jVBBJiZ1bkz) with layout animations. For this, I used a very simple animation engine I made, the [Universal Tween Engine](http://www.aurelienribon.com/blog/projects/universal-tween-engine/). It is generic enough to animate any object of any java project, not just swing components.

The new version of the application is not released yet, but as soon as I'll have the time, I'll share every source. You may have completed your project long ago, but I hope the answer may still be useful :)

[image]