# How to detect JFrame window minimize and maximize events?

Tags: java, swing, jframe, awt, windowlistener

Is there a way to an event listener to a JFrame object to detect when the user clicks the window maximize or minimize buttons?

Am using the JFrame object as follows:

`JFrame frame = new JFrame("Frame");`

Comment: Yes, I need to know when the window is resize so that I can re-draw the components inside the frame.

Comment: The methods `validate() and `repaint()` will be called automatically when the frame is resized, but you may need to update other data structures; see also [`AnimationTest`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3256941/230513).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use [WindowStateListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/event/WindowStateListener.html). [How to Write Window Listeners](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/windowlistener.html) tutorial demonstrates how to create window-related event handlers.

Answer (score 7):

Yes, you can do this by implementing `WindowListener` methods namely `windowIconified(WindowEvent e)` by `windowDeiconified(WindowEvent e)`.

For more details, visit [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/event/WindowListener.html)

Answer (score 7):

1. Create a frame and add a listener:

```js
JFrame frame = new JFrame();
frame.addWindowStateListener(new WindowStateListener() {
   public void windowStateChanged(WindowEvent arg0) {
      frame__windowStateChanged(arg0);
   }
});
```

2. Implement the listener:

```js
public void frame__windowStateChanged(WindowEvent e){
   // minimized
   if ((e.getNewState() & Frame.ICONIFIED) == Frame.ICONIFIED){
      _print("minimized");
   }
   // maximized
   else if ((e.getNewState() & Frame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH) == Frame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH){
      _print("maximized");
   }
}
```

Comment: is maximized means returned (showed) from minimized?