# trap maximize event and get new width of frame

Tags: java, swing

I tried to do this in Java:

```
public class Fram extends JFrame{
     public void init(){

        addWindowStateListener(new java.awt.event.WindowStateListener() {
            public void windowStateChanged(java.awt.event.WindowEvent evt) {
                wsc(evt);
            }
        });

    }
    private void wsc(java.awt.event.WindowEvent evt) {                     

        System.out.println(evt.getNewState() == Frame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
        System.out.println(this.getWidth());
    }                    
}
```

And the output is late.

When I maximize it the value is 360, but actual value is 1260.
How do I the get width after maximizing?

Comment: hmmm, downvote, i am really confused with this

Comment: You're never assigning a new width if I am not mistaken. You're only printing it out.

Comment: so how to get new width after maximized?

Comment: downvote??? seriously?

Comment: What happens when you try using a ComponentListener and listen in on the `componentResized(...)` method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a bit confusing. You actually have to implement ComponentListener. Then componentResized() is called. This will give you the correct width.

Answer (score 1):

> when i maximize it the value is 360 but actual value is 1260 hot to get width after maximize?

Try wrapping your code in a `SwingUtiltities.invokeLater()`. This will place the code at the end of the Event Dispatch Thread (EDT) so it should execute after the resizing code has been completed.

Answer (score 0):

ok i found the solution 
this post is not at all right.

[How to detect JFrame window minimize and maximize events?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11148950/how-to-detect-jframe-window-minimize-and-maximize-events)

this code, do the trick

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Frame;
import java.awt.event.ComponentEvent;
import java.awt.event.ComponentListener;

import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class Main extends JFrame implements ComponentListener {
  public Main() {
    addComponentListener(this);
  }

  public void componentHidden(ComponentEvent e) {
    System.out.println("componentHidden");
  }

  public void componentMoved(ComponentEvent e) {
    System.out.println("componentMoved");
  }

  public void componentResized(ComponentEvent e) {
    System.out.println("componentResized");

    if (getState() == Frame.ICONIFIED) {
      System.out.println("RESIZED TO ICONIFIED");
    } else if (getState() == Frame.NORMAL) {
      System.out.println("RESIZED TO NORMAL");
    } else {
      System.out.println("RESIZED TO MAXIMIZED");
    }
  }

  public void componentShown(ComponentEvent e) {
  }

  public static void main(String[] arg) {
    Main m = new Main();

    m.setVisible(true);
    m.setSize(new Dimension(300, 100));
    m.setLocation(50, 50);
  }
}
```