# How can I know if my JFrame is currently minimized?

Tags: java, swing, jframe

I have read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11148950/how-to-detect-jframe-window-minimize-and-maximize-events) and, in order to get the current "status" of my JFrame I have added a property like:

```
private static boolean isMinimized = false;
```

And then using [WindowsListener](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/event/WindowListener.html) I change this "property" within `windowIconified()`, `windowDeiconified()` methods, but I feel like I'm missing something.

Is there a property inside the `JFrame` class that let me know if my app is currently minimized or not? like... `myFrame.isMinimized()` or `myFrame.isIconified()`?

I feel like this is a really simple question, and I guess this already has an obvious answer, so if this is the case, feel free to mark it like duplicated.

Comment: *"How can I know if my JFrame is currently minimized?"*  Why does it matter?  See [What is the XY problem?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377)

Comment: @AndrewThompson I need this because I add a close button to a trayicon and I would like to unminimize(?) the app if this is minimized before let user decide if he/she really want to close the app

Comment: *"..I would like to unminimize(?) the app if this is minimized"*  Now it's sounding a bit like (a form of) premature optimization.  Just set the state to **not minimized** (without any check) using `Frame.setExtendedState(NORMAL)`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is there a property inside the JFrame class that let me know if my app is currently minimized or not? like... `myFrame.isMinimized()` or `myFrame.isIconified()`?

Yes.  You are looking for `myFrame.getExtendedState() & Frame.ICONIFIED != 0`.