# Rotate Image around character (JAVA)

Tags: java, image, rotation

Yes, i do know you can use AffineTransformation, however i want my sword image to rotate around  a character that i have made (black block drawn in graphics) 360 degrees visibly instead of just one rotation. Basically i want a rotation system like that of Terraria. I know how to get the x and y of the character so the question is: How do i make it rotate around a point that i define?
my code is set up like this

```
    f.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter(){
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e){
        swordSwinging=true;
    }
});
```

...

```
if(swordSwinging){
    //swinging code goes here
}

repaint();
```

Comment: What exactly is your question, you want an animated swing?

Comment: @M.M Yeah i want an animated swing

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).  Hot-link to the images, or generate them in code.

Comment: A short but complete example.  Add imports to the accepted answer (and link by URL to images), and that would be an SSCCE.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You mean something like...

[image]

(Please note, the red line is a guide line to indicate the angle from the center, you won't need it ;))

The fancy, pancy stuff is in the `getSwordHandlePoint` method, which calculates the point along the vector at which the handle should be placed...

```
public class TestSword {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new TestSword();
    }

    public TestSword() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
                } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
                } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
                } catch (UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Test");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
                frame.add(new SwordPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class SwordPane extends JPanel {

        private BufferedImage character;
        private BufferedImage sword;
        private double angle = 0;

        public SwordPane() {
            try {
                character = ImageIO.read(new File("character.png"));
                sword = ImageIO.read(new File("Sword.png"));
            } catch (IOException exp) {
                exp.printStackTrace();
            }

            Timer timer = new Timer(100, new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    angle += 10;
                    if (angle > 360) {
                        angle -= 360;
                    }
                    repaint();
                }
            });
            timer.setRepeats(true);
            timer.setCoalesce(true);
            timer.start();

        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            int width = character.getHeight() + sword.getWidth();
            int height = character.getHeight() + sword.getWidth();

            return new Dimension(width * 2, height * 2);
        }

        protected Point getSwordHandlePoint() {

            int radius = 272; // This is the height of the character...

            int x = Math.round(getWidth() / 2);
            int y = Math.round(getHeight() / 2);

            double rads = Math.toRadians(angle - 180); // Make 0 point out to the right...
            // If you add sword.getWidth, you might be able to change the above...
            int fullLength = Math.round((radius / 2f)) - sword.getWidth();

            // Calculate the outter point of the line
            int xPosy = Math.round((float) (x + Math.cos(rads) * fullLength));
            int yPosy = Math.round((float) (y - Math.sin(rads) * fullLength));

            return new Point(xPosy, yPosy);

        }

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {

            super.paintComponent(g);

            Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();

            int x = (getWidth() - character.getWidth()) / 2;
            int y = (getHeight() - character.getHeight()) / 2;

            g2d.drawImage(character, x, y, this);

            x = getWidth() / 2;
            y = getHeight() / 2;

            Point p = getSwordHandlePoint();
            g2d.setColor(Color.RED);
            g2d.drawLine(x, y, p.x, p.y);

            AffineTransform at = AffineTransform.getTranslateInstance(p.x, p.y);
            at.rotate(Math.toRadians(-angle));
            g2d.setTransform(at);
            g2d.drawImage(sword, 0, 0, this);

            g2d.dispose();

        }
    }
}
```

Now, my trig is hopeless, less then hopeless.  I "borrowed" the algorithm off the net and tweaked for my own needs...

Comment: You must embrace radians, for [example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3256941/230513). Your daughter will be asking for help with homework surprisingly soon. :-)

Comment: Thank you for the thourough response! The diagram really helped as well! I will try this code now!

Comment: Hey i tried the code out and modified it to fit my settings, however im getting an error on the timer code. I guess it wont accept a new ActionListener in the timer or accept any of this code timer.setRepeats(true);
            timer.setCoalesce(true);
            timer.start();

Comment: http://s10.postimage.org/h7xj6d4nd/Error.png  "The constructor Timer(int, new ActionListener(){}) is undefined"   also   "The method setRepeats(boolean) is undefined for the type Timer" and such for the methods that you listed

Comment: It sounds like you're use `java.util.Timer` instead of `javax.swing.Timer`

Comment: Oh! Thanks! That fixed the method errors. But it still doesnt want me to add an action listener

Comment: Make sure you've imported the `ActionListener`

Comment: Ah, fixed it thanks for that! Sorry about all the questions, im done now :P

Comment: @MadProgrammer this also uses `rotate(...)`, heh.

Comment: @M.M. Yes, it use affine transformation to rotate and position the sword, but what it does do is makes the sword orbit the player, which is far beyond just what rotate does, besides the OP already stated that they know how to apply a affine transformation

Answer (score 1):

The `Graphics2D` class, has a method `g2.rotate(...)`, call a `for loop` setting the rotate at one degree more, at a time, then invoke `g2.drawImage(...)`, in the loop, after the each change (if it's in the `paintComponent()` method, and the loop is outside - call `repaint()` in the for loop).

Comment: How does that get the sword at the end of the arm??

Comment: @MadProgrammer How can I help you?

Comment: I have a couple of ideas, but I have six month old to take care of, when I get a chance, I'll post :D