# Adding a delay in programs

Tags: java

I want to add a delay in my program using the `Thread.sleep(1000)` command (so making it stop for 1 second before continuing) but this means I also need to add the `throws InterruptedException`. However, I'm not sure where to put it.

My code basically looks like this right now:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Clock myClock = new Clock;   // new clock object.

    while (true) {
        myClock.tick();
    }
}
```

My other class:

```
public class Clock {
    // .. some constructors and stuff

    public void tick() {
        secondHand.draw();   // redraws the second hand to update every second
    }

    // .. some more methods and stuff
}
```

I want to only call the `tick()` method every 1 second, but I don't know where I can put the `Thread.sleep` and `throws InterruptedException` statements. Any help would be appreciated. Also any input on other ways I can make my clock tick and/or update would be helpful too!

Comment: If you're running in a graphics environment like Swing, use a [`javax.swing.Timer`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html) as I demonstrated in your previous question [How can I make a clock tick?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13116414/how-can-i-make-a-clock-tick/13116623#13116623)

Comment: @MadProgrammer you're just helping me out with all kinds of issues today! Thanks! I'm working with a StdDraw library from the StdLib.jar file found [here](http://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/stdlib/) (I am but a lowly college CS student)

Comment: By the way, if you pause for a clock it will slightly delay because you are not counting cpu spent time in previous code.

Comment: @59eagle We're all students ;). Be careful though, you are still running with the Swing environment, any long running or block processes will cause you program to look like it's hung/crashed. If you want to use something like `Thread.sleep` you are better of using a separate thread.  This means you become responsible for re-sync any updates to the UI back into the [Event Dispatching Thread](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html). I just don't want your next question to be, "Why does my program hang?" ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I want to only call the tick() method every 1 second

After the call to `tick()`, put a sleep on the current thread as follows:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Clock myClock = new Clock;   // new clock object.

    while (true) {
        myClock.tick();
        // wait for a second.
        try {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        }
        catch (InterruptedException ie) {
            // Handle the exception
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You don't "need" the reference to `currentThread`, `Thread.sleep(...)` will do the same thing. Just nit picking ;)

Comment: Right, sleep being a static method doesn't the reference to the current thread. Corrected it, thank you, @MadProgrammer.

Comment: You still got a +1 from me regardless ;)

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the flow of your program you will want to put the `Thread.sleep(1000);` statement into your controlling logic. By this I mean that whatever logic calls your `tick()` method would by convention be the best place to introduce your logic control - in this case your `Thread.sleep(1000);` statement.

Alas your calling logic should look something like this:

```
try {
    while (true) {
        Thread.sleep(1000);
        myClock.tick();
    }
} catch(InterruptedException e) {
    System.err.println("Something went wrong");
}
```

This approach ensures that if you have other controlling logic accessing your `tick()` method then it won't be tied into the 1 second delay. Different clients usually have different needs...

I prefer to wrap the entire while loop in the try catch block for scalability safe readability... By this I mean the if the logic in you `tick()` method gets more complex and you end up throwing more exceptions then you can simply add the catch clause to the one try catch block like so:

```
try {
    while (true) {
        Thread.sleep(1000);
        myClock.tick();
    }
} catch(InterruptedException e) {
    System.err.println("Something went wrong");
} catch(SomeNewExcetion e) {
    System.err.println("Something went wrong");
} catch(SomeOtherNewExceptoion e) {
    System.err.println("Something went wrong");
} catch(SomeFinalException e) {
    System.err.println("Something went wrong");
}
```

Comment: (I'm nit picking) But would you be able to explain the differences between you example and Vikdor's (it's not wrong, but a little more explanation might help the OP ;))

Comment: That's a fair point, but I would suggest that the main reason for wrapping the loop inside the exception handler is so that you don't end up with a run away loop, that, if for some reason, something goes bad, the loop will be automatically exited ;) - IMHO

Answer (score 1):

You could use either `javax.swing.Timer` or `java.util.Timer` to achieve the same results.

The `javax.swing.Timer` has the advantage of when it's triggered, the `ActionPerformed` method is executed within the Event Dispatching Thread, making updates to the UI easier.

**java.util.Timer**

```
timer = new Timer();
timer.schedule(new TickTock (), 1000);

public class TickTock extends TimerTask {
    public void run() {
        System.out.println("Tick tock!");
    }
}
```

**javax.swing.Timer**

```
Timer timer = new Timer(1000, new ActionListener() {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        System.out.println("Tick tock!");
        repaint();
    }
});
timer.setRepeats(true);
timer.setCoalesce(true);
timer.start();
```

You can have read through [How to Use Swing Timers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html) for more info on `javax.swing.Timer`

Answer (score 1):

Although I would not normally suggest it.

In this case you do not really need to code for this being interrupted.
Hide it by wrapping with a runtime exception.

```
public class Clock {
    // .. some constructors and stuff

    public void tick() {
       secondHand.draw();   // redraws the second hand to update every second
    }
    public void wait() {
       try {
           Thread.sleep(1000)
       } catch(InterruptedException e) {
           throw new RuntimeException("Don't know how to handle this", e);
       }
    }
   // .. some more methods and stuff
}
```

Answer (score 0):

its Very Simple in java

```
TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(2);
```