# How to rotate a shape made up of line segments

Tags: java, algorithm, rotation, geometry, line-segment

Hello I am making a game in java. I am using a collection of lines to represent a shape to detect collisions. I need to be able to rotate this shape by degrees or radians
[image]

As you can see from the diagram above the shape is a collection of line segments with 2 points a and b. I need to know how would I rotate all of lines together and still retain the shape.

Comment: Just rotate all the points independently, as described in the answer to [your earlier question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22491178/how-to-rotate-a-point-around-another-point)

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like a job for `AffineTransform` (assuming you're doing 2D)

Something to this effect:

```
Point2D rotatedPoints = new Point2D[yourPoints.length];
AffineTransform at = new AffineTransform();
at.rotate(Math.toRadians(yourDegreeRotation), xToRotateAround, yToRotateAround);
at.transform(yourPoints, 0, rotatedPoints, 0, yourPoints.length);
```