# Rotation of a point around another point in pitch axis in C

Tags: algorithm, rotation

I use the following code (from [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22491252/3520059)) to rotate point around another point.
It work great for the yaw rotation axis.

How do I modifiy this code for a pitch axis rotation?

```
double x1 = point.x - center.x;
double y1 = point.y - center.y;

double x2 = x1 * Math.cos(angle) - y1 * Math.sin(angle));
double y2 = x1 * Math.sin(angle) + y1 * Math.cos(angle));

point.x = x2 + center.x;
point.y = y2 + center.y;
```

Comment: change all `y` to `z`

Comment: It doesn't work, it rotates in Roll axis. Thx anyway.

Comment: then change `x` to `z` instead... the axis of rotation should not be changing in the rotation formula so if `z` is missing you rotating around `z` (usually roll)... if `x` (usually pitch) and if `y` (usually yaw) ... your notation is different so you have to try which combination is doing what you need. Also with more complex transformations you would be better of using [4x4 homogenous transform matrices](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28084380/2521214)

Comment: Same result: roll axis. I may have a mistake somewhere. For information, I already use matrix transformation, but for single axis rotation, I try to avoid unnecessary multiplication.

Comment: render the matrix as in the link ... its possible you got corrupted axises ...