# Rotating a point around another point in a game loop (Java)

Tags: java, rotation, geometry, game-loop

I'm trying to create a method which rotates a point around another point in Java for a Asteroids clone that I want to make.Right now I have 2 Point instances called point and center.The code for my method is this:

```
public void Rotate(double angle){
       double a; 
       int x,y,distance;
       distance=30;
       a=Math.atan2((int)(point.getX()-center.getX()),(int)(point.getY()-center.getY()));
       a=a+angle;
       x=(int)(Math.cos(a)*distance);
       y=(int)(Math.sin(a)*distance);
       point.setLocation(x,y);   
}
```

And the code for my gameloop is this:

```
while (true){
      game.Rotate(10);
      game.repaint();
      Thread.sleep(10);
}
```

The problem is that the distance between the point and the center increases or decreases and I don't know why.Can somebody please tell me what's wrong?

EDIT [PROBLEM SOLVED]:
For anyone interested here is how I solved the problem using the help that I got from the answers below:
First, the Rotate function:

```
public void Rotate(double angle){
    double x,y;
    double distance=60;
    x=Math.round(center.getX() + (Math.cos(Math.toRadians(angle))*distance));
    y=Math.round(center.getY() + (Math.sin(Math.toRadians(angle))*distance));
    point.setLocation(x,y);
}
```

Then I made another method called move:

```
public void move(){
    angle+=2;
    if(angle>360){
        angle=0;
    }
    Rotate(angle);
}
```

And this is the game loop code:

```
while(true){
        main.move();
        main.repaint();
        Thread.sleep(10);
    }
```

Thanks again for your support.

Comment: `y=(int)(Math.sin(a)*distance);`

Comment: Thanks for the reply but even with this it still doesn't work.

Comment: Not sure if [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12964983/rotate-image-around-character-java/12971987#12971987) will help

Comment: This actually solved all of my probelms.Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

You need to realize [affine trnsformation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Affine_transformation) of 2D space. There is [example](http://www.javalobby.org/java/forums/t19387.html) how you can made it with java AffineTransform class. But if you don't want to do it though java Graphics there is algorithm in three steps:

1. place object at center of rotation:

   x1=x-centerX;

   y1=y-centerY;
2. rotate object on angle alpha(in radians):

   x2=x1*Math.cos(alpha)+y1*Math.sin(alpha);

   y2=x1*Math.sin(alpha)-y1.Math.cos(alpha);
3. return object at it place:

   x3=x2+centerX;

   y3=y2+centerY;

This operations can be simply converts into matrix, and then you can use matrix algebra for your purpose.

Answer (score 0):

You rotate point around coordinate origin. To rotate it about center, use

```
  x=center.getX() + (int)(Math.cos(a)*distance);
  y=center.getY() + (int)(Math.sin(a)*distance);
```