# How to create this custom component?

Tags: java, swing, layout-manager, graphics2d, java-2d

[LEC Cube Software](http://profholzer.files.wordpress.com/2010/03/ledcube_designer.png) as seen below.

[image]

Any good idea how to draw the component on the left side in a Java application?

Thought about Java2D. But I think with Java2D you can only draw those lines and no checkboxes.
Perhaps any good LayoutManager to solve this?

Comment: That doesn't look like a cube to me, I'm guessing someone calculated the points on the paper and hard-coded them.

Comment: Out of curiousity, can't you use the [standard Swing checkbox](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JCheckBox.html)? For the positions, you need to [choose a projection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graphical_projection) and do the math.

Comment: Of course i would use the standard JCheckbox. I thought about drawing with Graphics2D. There i think you cannot use JCheckbox. You only can use methodes loke drawLine, etc.

Comment: Click on this [`AnimationTest`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3256941/230513) to add text fields; resize to see the effect of the default layout.

Answer (score 2):

With [checkboxes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JCheckBox.html) and [lines](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/geom/Line2D.html), using some [model of a cube](https://gist.github.com/4376898) (if it's resizable; see below) and [no layout manager](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/none.html).

[image: cube]

Comment: This cube model is nice. But how to position a JCheckbox within this cube??

Comment: Well, every awt.Component has a [`setLocation`](http://goo.gl/ZVHQG) method; the task would be to recalculate the correct positions based on the cube model (which itself would change it's size when the window is resized (again, only if the whole thing is resizable)).