# Full-screen frame-rate limit conundrum

Tags: java, swing, awt, fullscreen, frame-rate

my game(framework) can't go faster than 30 frames per second(about 33 ms between update calls) in full-screen. I use a Timer for the loop. Actually it gets a bit more complicated, since when i decrease the delay incrementally, the time between calls i measure goes nuts. It jumps form the set delay to twice or more the expected value. The threshold seems to be 30 ms. No problem in windowed mode, where discrepancies start to appear at the 4 ms threshold. Both modes act normally at higher delays. Here are parts of the code that I think are pertinent.

```
fps = 30;       
timer = new Timer(1000/fps, new ActionListener() {          
@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
    tick();             
}
```

Above is the Timer setup. Below is the rest.

```
private void tick(){
    update(gameTime);
    draw(gameTime);     
}
```

Here is my Graphics(2D) and BufferedImage.

```
    public DrawBatch(DeviceManager deviceManager) {
    this.deviceManager = deviceManager;
    color = Color.MAGENTA;
    bufferedImage = deviceManager.getBufferedImage();       
    bufferedGraphics = (Graphics2D)bufferedImage.getGraphics();bufferedGraphics = (Graphics2D)bufferedImage.getGraphics();
    bufferedGraphics.setBackground(color);
    bufferedGraphics.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
    bufferedGraphics.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_RENDERING, RenderingHints.VALUE_RENDER_QUALITY);
    bufferedGraphics.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_STROKE_CONTROL, RenderingHints.VALUE_STROKE_PURE); 
}
```

The draw(GameTime gameTime) method begins with this method:

```
    public void begin(){
    bufferedGraphics.clearRect(0, 0, bufferedImage.getWidth(), bufferedImage.getHeight());  
}
```

Now we can draw using bufferedGraphics. draw(GT gT) ends with this.(inspired by xna)

```
    public void end(){
    if(deviceManager.isFullScreen())deviceManager.getGraphics().drawImage(bufferedImage, 0,0, null);
    else deviceManager.getGraphics().drawImage(bufferedImage, 3,25, null);      
    deviceManager.getGraphics().dispose();      
    bufferedImage.flush();  
}
```

I recycle the same BufferedImage since making new one(along with a Graphics object) made one hell of a memory leak. Don't know if using the same Graphics object instead of doing .dispose() / new Graphics every frame.

In windowed mode, the BufferedImage is drawn on jFrame.getGraphics() and in fulls-creen on 
graphicDevice.getFullScreenWindow().getGraphics().

Here is the full-screen setup.

```
public void setFS(){
    jFrame.setVisible(false);
    jFrame.dispose();
    jFrame.setIgnoreRepaint(true);
    jFrame.setResizable(false);
    jFrame.setUndecorated(true);
    graphicDevice.setFullScreenWindow(jFrame);
    graphicDevice.getFullScreenWindow().setIgnoreRepaint(true);
    graphicDevice.setDisplayMode(new DisplayMode(width, height, 32, 60));   
    jFrame.setVisible(true);        
    fullScreen = true;      
}
```

And the windowed setup.

```
public void setW(){
    jFrame.setVisible(false);
    jFrame.dispose();   
    jFrame.setIgnoreRepaint(true);
    jFrame.setResizable(false);
    jFrame.setUndecorated(false);
    graphicDevice.setFullScreenWindow(null);
    jFrame.setSize(width, height);      
    jFrame.setVisible(true);
    jFrame.getContentPane().setPreferredSize(new Dimension(800, 600));          
    jFrame.pack();      
    fullScreen = false;
}
```

Any idea why the different behaviors of the modes?
(Except for the frame-rate and some potential memory leaks, the program runs smoothly.)

Comment: I believe your ticks get called faster/slower because the swing Event Dispatch Thread is a thread of its own which your timer has no control over. You must limit the number of calls in a given timeframe in another way.

Comment: A number of things spring to mind, the one that seems to make sense is that the EDT is becoming overwhelmed and the timer is simply stacking events on it. Timer has a method called [setCoalesce](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/Timer.html#setCoalesce(boolean)) which will compress multiple, short requests into a single request onto the EDT

Comment: Yeah. EDT choked on `graphicDevice.getFullScreenWindow().getGraphics()` going off every cycle. Was EDT a good idea for a game loop? One downside is that I can't use some of SwingUtilities. Know any other?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Theoretically, the timer's period can be no shorter than the time taken to render one frame. Practically, it needs to be longer or you'll immediately saturate the timer's shared thread. You'll need to [profile](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2064427/230513) to be sure. Calls to `drawImage()` typically dominate, even without scaling. This [`AnimationTest`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3256941/230513) displays a moving average of the render time over the last few `FRAMES`. You can use the approach to tune your implementation to suit your slowest acceptable target platform.

Comment: Booyah! Thanks to the profile suggestion I noticed that getting a new Graphics object from full-screen window took a lot of time. Now I create a Graphics object at mode(full-screen/windowed) change. The frame-rate is fixed. There a new problem with switching between modes and loosing the Graphics object, but I'm sure it's easy to fix. Thanks trashgod.

Comment: @Sasha-san: Glad it helped. The graphics context from `getGraphics()` is ephemeral. It's OK from `BufferedImage`, but be careful about how you get it in your `DeviceManager`.

Comment: A followup question then. Jframe.getGraphics() gets the Grpahics object of that frame(reference to) or creates a new one? Not too clear on that one.

Comment: nvm. HashCodes indicate new instances.

Comment: @Sasha-san: Yes, and relying on a stale reference is a common error in the [tag:Swing] tag. Sorry I missed your followup question.