# Adding JTextfield to JPanel over paint layer

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, awt, jtextfield

I want to add a `JTextfield` to my `JPanel`. I am overriding the paint method and doing some drawing, because its a game.

If I am adding the `JTextField` it is not visible. If I know the position, I can click on it and I can even add some text, but the `JTextField` is flickering.

Is there any solution, that I can add a `JTextField` to my `JPanel` over the paint layer, so that is every time visible?

EDIT:

If you override paintComponent instead of paint, everything is working and you can simply add an `JTextField`. Thanks to trashgod.

Comment: i dont understand, can't u just do `panel.add(textfield)`? and then use `textfield.setVisible(true);`

Comment: No I can't. I am guessing that my paint method, which will draw over the whole screen override this textfield.

Comment: "Swing programs should override `paintComponent()` instead of overriding `paint()`."—[*Painting in AWT and Swing: The Paint Methods*](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html#callbacks).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Click anywhere on this [`AnimationTest`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3256941/230513) to add a text field. Note the use of `invokeLater()` and the call to `super.paintComponent(g)`. Resize the frame to see how the default layout works.

Comment: if you still have problems, please edit your question to include an [sscce](http://sscce.org/) that exhibits what you encounter.

Comment: Thanks, I am looking through the code and trying to understand, but this is the exact thing, I wanna to have.

Comment: Take some time with it; don't hesitate to use it as a basis for any update.