# Need help to write an algorithm for rectangles to move in circles

Tags: java, algorithm, swing

I wrote a program that makes rectangles move. But so far they move only up and down. Now I need to make them move in circles(endless). Here is what I have already done:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import javax.swing.*;

class GrimMain {
    static JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    //final static List<Rect> rectangles = new ArrayList<Rect>();
    //final static int count = 0;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        DrawingComponent fps = new DrawingComponent();
        int pos = 100;
        Rect r1 = new Rect(pos+100, 100, 30, 30, Color.red);
        Rect r2 = new Rect(pos+140, 100, 30, 30, Color.blue);
        Rect r3 = new Rect(pos+180, 100, 30, 30, Color.green);

        fps.addRect(r1);
        fps.addRect(r2);
        fps.addRect(r3);
        fps.animate();

        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        fps.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(800, 600));
        frame.getContentPane().add(fps);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}

class Rect {
    int x;
    int y;
    int height;
    int width;
    Color color;
    Rect(int x, int y, int width, int height, Color color) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.width = width;
        this.height = height;
        this.color = color;
    }

    public void draw(Graphics g) {
        g.setColor(color);
        g.fillRect(x, y, width, height);
    }

    public int getY() {
        return y;
    }
    public int getX() {
        return x;
    }

    public int getHeight() {
        return height;
    }

    public void setY(int y) {
        this.y = y;
    }
    public void setX(int y) {
        this.x = x;
    }
}

class DrawingComponent extends JComponent {
    private static final int ANIMATION_DELAY = 10;
    private List<Rect> rectList = new ArrayList<Rect>();
    private int deltaY = 2;

    DrawingComponent() {
    }

    public void animate() {
// here is the part with animation
        new Timer(ANIMATION_DELAY, new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                for (Rect rect : rectList) {
                    int y = rect.getY();
                    if (y + rect.getHeight() >= getHeight()) {
                        deltaY = -Math.abs(deltaY);
                    }
                    else if (y <= 0) {
                        deltaY = Math.abs(deltaY);
                    }

                    rect.setY(y + deltaY);
                }
                repaint();
            }
        }).start();
    }

    public void addRect(Rect rect) {
        rectList.add(rect);
    }

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        for (Rect rect : rectList) {
            rect.draw(g);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: A related example is examined [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3256941/230513).

Answer (score 2):

In this code you are only changing the y coordinate.

```
for (Rect rect : rectList) {
                    int y = rect.getY();
                    if (y + rect.getHeight() >= getHeight()) {
                        deltaY = -Math.abs(deltaY);
                    }
                    else if (y <= 0) {
                        deltaY = Math.abs(deltaY);
                    }

                    rect.setY(y + deltaY);
                }
```

You can similarly change the x coordinate as well according to the circle's equation.

For example if the centre of circle is `(x0,y0)` and radius is `r`, you can set the initial value of theta, make small changes in theta and update the new x and y coordinates of the rectangle.

```
x = x0 + r*cos(theta_initial + delta_theta)
y = y0 + r*sin(theta_initial + delta_theta)
```

Answer (score 0):

This code is taken from TheChernoProject 3D Game Programming [episode 5](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dwn_UrItwfw)

```
int x = (int) (Math.sin(System.currentTimeMillis() % 2000.0 / 2000 * Math.PI * 2) * 200);
int y = (int) (Math.cos(System.currentTimeMillis() % 2000.0 / 2000 * Math.PI * 2) * 200);
```

All you need to do is place this inside your paintComponent or whatever you use to render your rectangles and then use the x & y values.