# Swing/AWT Double Buffering very slow on Linux

Tags: java, linux, swing, graphics, awt

I have an AWT Canvas within a JFrame (I know that Swing and AWT shouldn't be used simultaneously but it works well on Windows so I don't think the problem is caused by this) and using a BufferStrategy from the Canvas to draw on screen. It runs pretty smooth on Windows but when I tried to run it on Ubuntu 12.04 it became unbearably slow. Not just the rendering but JFrame is also unresponsive. When I comment out the double buffering and rendering part it's smooth again. I have an ATI graphics card which is no longer supported so I'm using the open source video drivers, but when I run another program which uses OpenGL it's not slow like Swing/AWT one. Why could this be happening?

Main render:

```
...

private void render()
{
    bs = gamePanel.getBufferStrategy();

    Graphics g = bs.getDrawGraphics();

    currentState.render(g);

    g.dispose();
    bs.show();
}

...
```

I don't draw anything in currentstate.render() method except a black rectangle that fills the screen.

edit: OK so I tracked down the real problem, it's my game loop. I'm using a while loop within a new Thread to update and render(render code provided above). If I use `paint()` method of Canvas it runs smoothly but then I don't have any control over my frame rate. Why is a while loop slowing down my program?

Game Loop looks like this:

```
    while(running)
    {
        update();
        render();
    }
```

Comment: Graphics Card has nothing to do with Java Swing Buffer Rates. Its the code (which would be nice to see)

Comment: Try this [`AnimationTest`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3256941/230513).

Comment: @BDillan I added some of my code which I thought was relevant, if you need to see more I will add that too

Comment: @trashgod AnimationTest seems to run just fine, it's the double buffering that affects my program I think

Comment: `JPanel` is double buffered by default.

Comment: This is AWT's fault then?

Comment: Consider making a [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for better help sooner.

Comment: I have edited my question, could you please take a look at it again?

Comment: What's the delay in the update cycle, how do you control the frame rate?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I put `Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().sync();` in my render method which appears to fix it. However you should put only if it's Linux
I used the code bellow to do that

```
public static String getOsName() {
    String OS = null;
    if(OS == null) { OS = System.getProperty("os.name"); }
    return OS;
}

public static boolean isUnix() { return getOsName().startsWith("Linux"); }
```