# Move an entity "forward" in it's trajectory not working as intended

Tags: java, swing, awt

I am currently making an AWT game engine, a simple one just getting conversant with AWT. I am currently working on the physics of the game. I am trying to implement a function that moves the entity forward on it's direction from the north line, or the x axis. This is the code I am using to achieve this:

```
public void move(double d) {
    oldX = x;
    oldY = y;
    double angle = Math.toRadians(getDirection());
    int dx = (int)  Math.round(Math.cos(angle) * d);
    int dy = (int)  Math.round(Math.sin(angle) * d);
    setLocation(x + dx, y + dy);

    System.out.println("x = " + x);
    System.out.println("y = " + y);
    System.out.println("direction = " + angle);
    System.out.println("----------");
}
```

and I call this code in this snippet:

```
        for(Entity e : entities) {
            if(!e.getLevel().equals(this)) {
                return;
            }
            e.move(3); //testing the code atm
            e.changeDirection(e.getDirection() + 3);
        }
```

The problem is that it won't go in a circle, or oval trajectory as I would expect when you have a vector forward (`move(int i)`) method and changing the direction by 3 every tick as the force acting on the vector, or gravity if we were talking about Earth orbiting objects. This is the expected behaviour.

However, this is what actually happens:

[gif demonstration - imgur](http://i.imgur.com/eXXZkPx.gifv)

Could you tell me why this behavior is occurring and how I could solve this? Thanks

---

The actual problem, as @harold says, is not the maths but the rendering. Here is what the fixed code to render the 2d entity looks like:

```
    for(Entity e : entities) {
        AffineTransform trans = new AffineTransform();
        trans.setTransform(identity);
        Point mouse = MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().getLocation();
        SwingUtilities.convertPointToScreen(mouse, this);
        trans.rotate(Math.toRadians(e.getDirection()), e.getX(), e.getY());
 //changed from trans.rotate(Me.getDirection(), e.getX() + e.image.getWidth(null)/2, e.getY() + e.image.getHeight(null)/2);
        trans.translate(e.getX(), e.getY());
        g2d.drawImage(e.getImage(), trans, this);

    }
```

Comment: The math checks out. Are you drawing using just the x or just the y coordinate? Btw over time it slowly drifts due to accumulation of rounding errors, if you're simulating a 2-body system you can just compute the position at time t directly.

Comment: @harold I just checked the rendering method and I noticed massive mistakes. Urghh. Must have been yesterday when I was programming at 4 am... Oh well. Thanks. I will post the changes in the main post but you can post an answer and I will accept it.

Comment: Possible [duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3256269/230513).

Comment: @trashgod it was a problem with my translation parameters, ie. the rotation was not centered on the image.