# Getting a Circle to orbit around another

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, animation

I have been doing a ton of research and none of the questions I found really answered my question and that is why I am making this post.

I want to create a program that will have a circle, a "planet" orbit around a another circle, a "Sun."

I have the static gui set up, but nothing I have found in my book or online really helps solves the orbit problem. Any ideas?

NOTE: eventually the program needs to be multithreaded (one for the planet and one for the Sun) but I want to break the problem down before I get back into trying to get that to work so for now please disregard it.

GUI:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import javax.swing.JPanel;


public class PlanetsGUI extends JPanel
{   
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Override
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) 
{
    super.paintComponent(g); 
    setBackground(Color.BLACK);
    paintSun(g);
    paintPlanet(g);
}

public void paintSun(Graphics g)
{
    super.paintComponent(g);

    //create circle and fill it as yellow to represent the sun
    g.setColor(Color.YELLOW);
    g.drawOval(100, 75, 75, 75);
    g.fillOval(100, 75, 75, 75);
} //end paintSun


public void paintPlanet(Graphics g)
{
    //create circle and fill it as blue to represent the orbiting planet
    g.setColor(Color.BLUE);
    g.drawOval(35, 50, 50, 50);
    g.fillOval(35, 50, 50, 50);


}//end paintPlanet

}//end class PlanetsGUI
```

MAIN:

```
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import javax.swing.JFrame;


public class OrbitingPlants_main 
{
  private static final ExecutorService execute + Executors.newFixedThreadPool(2);

public static void main(String[] args) 
{

    PlanetsGUI planet = new PlanetsGUI();
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();

    frame.setTitle("Orbiting Planets");
    frame.setSize(300, 300);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.add(planet); //add panel onto frame
    frame.setVisible(true);

    //PlanetsLogic r = new PlanetsLogic();
    //Thread sun = new Thread(sun);
    //sun.start();

    //execute.submit(new );





}//end main     


}//end class
```

Comment: Where you draw the image of the "planet", use variables to change the x and y coordinates to imitate "rotation" around the sun. You can use the unit circle ( originX + sin(value), originY + cos(value) )

Comment: @StevenKimarro Im confused how do you get a value for 'value' that is inserted into sin and cos? Do I hard code in the unit circle values?

Comment: Basically the transformation of a trig equation is as follows: a*sin(b*x + c) where a is amplitude, b is the stretch, and c is the offset. Play around with it to get the perfect "circular movement".

Comment: Would that make 'originX' = to my xSun ( which is equal to 100)?

Comment: @StevenKimarro so the quantity asin(bx + c) would be: a = SunsHeight b = SunWidth, x = X corrd of the Sun and C = the spacing between the sun and planet, lets say 25px? Or do I have this all wrong?

Comment: the origin would be the position of the sun, yes.  In this case a = rotation distance from the sun (how far it is from the sun), b = how fast it rotates, and x = time, and c should be 0.

Comment: http://funprogramming.org/68-Circular-motion-reviewed.html

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/95975/discussion-between-user3712626-and-steven-kimarro).

Comment: See also this complete [example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3256941/230513).

Answer (score 1):

You're hard-coding where the images are being drawn, for example:

```
g.setColor(Color.BLUE);
g.drawOval(35, 50, 50, 50);
g.fillOval(35, 50, 50, 50);
```

making for images that can **never** change.

Instead get rid of the hard coded numbers and use **variables**, values that can change:

```
g.setColor(Color.BLUE);
// variables used below are fields declared in the class
g.drawOval(planetX, planetY, planetW, planetW); // probably don't need this line
g.fillOval(planetX, planetY, planetW, planetW);
```

and then change the values in your thread (or better, Swing Timer).

As far as "orbiting", that would be using the equations of a circle (or ellipse if you wanted to be extremely precise), and perhaps using a parametric equation to determine your planetX and planetY values.

Comment: this is more of a digression question, but would I put those three lines into run()? or would I use a repaint() in run()?

Comment: @user3712626: those lines stay right where they originally are. Within `run()` you'd update their values, and call `repaint()`.

Comment: I understand parameter equations for the circle to x = cos(t) and y = sin(t), but in this program, what would be t?

Comment: or would I create a swing timer for lets say 1000ms and that is my t value?

Comment: @user3712626: Rather than ask, try, experiment, see what happens!

Comment: I am having trouble getting it set up. I have Timer time = new Timer(1000,this); But It won't let me use time within the Cos because it wants it to be a double. Any ideas?

Comment: @user3712626: Please keep trying, and consider asking fewer questions. You're not going to learn if you don't figure some of these things on your own. Seriously.