# GUI Application and measuring the running time

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

(1) I wrote a question about this issue but I think I did not state the problem correctly so I removed it. To get to the point, in my GUI application, I notice when I want to measure the running time taken by a method using `System.currentTimeMillis();`, the time becomes very short and unrealistic comparing with the standard way of running `jar` file via terminal or console, does Java Swing make some effects here?

(2) Since I want to keep my GUI and also solve this issue, I read about the possibility of disabling JIT, how can I write it as a piece of code in my program so when it runs, JIT is disabled during the runtime of my application only.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run your program using the [`-Xint`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/windows/java.html) option, which "Runs the application in interpreted-only mode. Compilation to native code is disabled, and all bytecode is executed by the interpreter. The performance benefits offered by the just in time (JIT) compiler are not present in this mode."

As a concrete example, this [`AnimationTest`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3256941/230513) displays the average time spent in `paintComponent()` using `System.nanoTime()`. With the `-Xint` option, the time remains fairly constant:

```
java -Xint -cp build/classes overflow.AnimationTest
```

Without the option, i.e. *with* compilation to native code, it's easy to see a secular decrease in paint time, sometimes by as much as an order of magnitude:

```
java -cp build/classes overflow.AnimationTest
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. How can I do that as a code in my class constructor since my application will be run by unexperienced people.

Comment: You can specify that option when deploying via [tag:java-web-start], but I would't.